# Discordia bot DM sending breaks my script

Tags: lua, discord, luvit

I am trying to make a bot for my server on discord using Discordia, but when I try to use `member:send(str)`, all I get is Uncaught Error: `C:/luvit/deps/coro-channel.lua:62: C:/luvit/deps/discordia/libs/containers/User.lua:91: attempt to call method 'getPrivateChannel' (a nil value)`
it does send the dm, but then the code breaks and the bot doesn't run anymore, how can I fix this?

member is a variable that gets the member from message

`local member = message.member`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post the entire block of code you're sending the message from? I'd also like to know what version of Discordia you're using - judging by your description of the behavior, this could be a bug with Discordia.

Comment: `if message.content:lower() == prefix..'createdm' then`
 `message.channel:send("<@!"..memberid.."> ".. "Sent!")`   
         `member:send("test")`
`end`

here is the code, I was trying to test dm sending when this error popped up
I am using Discordia 2.8.3 if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to recreate the issue, albeit with a different error that I suspect is due to me not having all your code to debug with.
The bot will send the DM and post a message, then crash due to error.
You have this code:

```lua
if message.content:lower() == prefix..'createdm' then
      message.channel:send("<@!"..memberid.."> ".. "Sent!")
      message.member:send("test") --message.member is able to inherit the send method from message.author
end
```

I don't know how you find memberid, so I defined it like this:
`memberid = message.member:__hash()`
It is called every time a message is sent, and it sends a message. This means the bot is going to call this and read its own messages. While the bot will not continue into the if statement because its message is not `<prefix>createdm`, it will still try to get memberid and evaluate the if statement. I do not know how bot users differ from human users in their account metadata, but I strongly suspect there is some difference and this is your issue.

I believe adding this to your code, at the beginning of your message callback (before your do anything else to evaluate a message) will fix your problem.

```
if message.author == client.user then
   return
end
```

`client` here is whatever you assigned `discordia.Client()` to.

Comment: I used message.author:send() before and still got the same error, it has to be something with the member value being nil when the method is called. also, both message.member:send() and message.author:send() sent the dm to me, but then the error appears in console and the script stops working.

Comment: I've created a new answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, it seems my problem was that memberid was assigned to message.member.id, not message.member:__hash()

Answer (score 0):

```
if message.content:lower() == prefix..'createdm' then
      message.channel:send("<@!"..memberid.."> ".. "Sent!") -- member.id !!!
      message.member:send("test") --message.member is able to inherit the send method from message.author
end
```